# Deep filtering of a list of dictionaries based on two properties

Tags: python

I'm trying to find an efficient way to handle this problem. I have an list of dictionaries with over 400k entries. I need to first find all the entries that share a common key, let's say 'pallet-id' from that list and then from that sub-list verify that all those share the same 'location' key. I'm only interested in getting from that initial list the entries that have a similar 'pallet-id' but only if one of those have a different 'location' than the rest.

Ex.

This would be working with pallet-id 123456

```
entry1 = {'location': 'LOC1', 'pallet-id': '123456', ...}  
entry2 = {'location': 'LOC1', 'pallet-id': '123456', ...}  
entry3 = {'location': 'LOC1', 'pallet-id': '123456', ...}  
entry4 = {'location': 'LOC1', 'pallet-id': '123456', ...}
```

Since all share the same location, I don't care about this.

This would be working with pallet-id 5555

```
entry1 = {'location': 'LOC1', 'pallet-id': '5555', ...}  
entry2 = {'location': 'LOC1', 'pallet-id': '5555', ...}  
entry3 = {'location': 'LOC2', 'pallet-id': '5555', ...}  
entry4 = {'location': 'LOC1', 'pallet-id': '5555', ...}
```

In this case since one has a different location I would like to store those 4 entries.

The problem that I'm having is that the report is taking infinite amount of time by just checking each pallet-id and then looking for the rest of the same pallet-id in the initial list, is there a more efficient way of handling this?

Comment: Instead of a vague description of what you want to do, how about a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you post your code? Maybe we could give you some pointers then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting loops is a bad idea here as it leads to quadratic time complexity. You can do it in linear time though:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

pal = itemgetter('pallet-id')
pal_loc = itemgetter('pallet-id', 'location')

# unique pallet-id, location combos
pallocs = set(map(pal_loc, entries))
# set([('5555', 'LOC1'), ('5555', 'LOC2'), ('123456', 'LOC1')])

# count pallet-id occurrences in the unique combos
count = Counter(pl[0] for pl in pallocs) 
# Counter({'5555': 2, '123456': 1})

# filter the entries for pallet-ids with counts greater than 1
filtered_entries = [e for e in entries if count[pal(e)] > 1]
```